# Is there an equivalent of mt.dialog for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.ios

It would be great to use the structures used in mt.dialog across multiple platforms. In particular, I would like to be able to auto-generate WPF-based forms using class members like so:

```
    [Entry (KeyboardType=UIKeyboardType.Url, Placeholder="n/a")]
    public string Url;

    [Entry (Placeholder="n/a")]
    public string Terms;

    [Entry (Placeholder="Your feedback")]
    public string Feedback;

    [Entry (KeyboardType=UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress, Placeholder="Your email address")]
    public string Email;

    [RadioSelection("Mood")]
    public Moods Mood;
```

Comment: If I had to guess, https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Why would there be an equivalent to **any** mono-control in WPF? This sort of question would make sense if you ask for equivalents between Silverlight and WPF which are both developed by Microsoft but not if you are dealing with a framework independently developed by some 3rd party.